# Buffer cannot be null. Parameter name: buffer

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written code to send an email with a link to a URL, which the user has to click for confirmation.

Sample Link:
http://localhost:3531/VerificationModule/VerifyEmail.aspx?TemplateID=519457608&F960866879F669E=Tw5NpFeW9HsAqc_Ap5dmOwqkZ041pFQGYLxRV-puumtHsfhrTYtDe51uCbGV44Kc1X3n6cggsynfqRmh74ie535ymkvATeK5Jii11tOMIZDZ_GVB8QolLeMU5i6KWEZculKhM0IOhYFaMc-DsB

But when the user clicks the link, it gets opened in the browser, but displays the following error.

> **"Buffer cannot be null. Parameter name: buffer"**
>
> Please find below the stack trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Buffer cannot be null.
 Parameter name: buffer]
 System.IO.MemoryStream..ctor(Byte[] buffer, Boolean writable) +9629927
 System.IO.MemoryStream..ctor(Byte[] buffer) +6
 Auth.IdentityTokenXChangeData.Deserialize(String base64Package) +187
 Auth.IdentityTokenXChange.TrySniffIdentityToken(HttpRequest req, String& sessionId, String& sessionTag, String& returnUrl) +244
 Auth.IdentityModule.OnBeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +365
 System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  +220
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&   completedSynchronously) +120`
```

This is eating up my day. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Got a clue on the error..
I believe the problem is with Encoded value in the QueryString

```
("F960866879F669E=Tw5NpFeW9HsAqc_Ap5dmOwqkZ041pFQGYLxRV-puumtHsfhrTYtDe51uCbGV44Kc1X3n6cggsynfqRmh74ie535ymkvATeK5Jii11tOMIZDZ_GVB8QolLe‌​MU5i6KWEZculKhM0IOhYFaMc-DsB") -
```

The Base64 Decode is returning 'null' for some reasons.

```
Method -
'System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode
("F960866879F669E=Tw5NpFeW9HsAqc_Ap5dmOwqkZ041pFQGYLxRV-puumtHsfhrTYtDe51uCbGV44Kc1X3n6cggsynfqRmh74ie535ymkvATeK5Jii11tOMIZDZ_GVB8QolLe‌​MU5i6KWEZculKhM0IOhYFaMc-DsB")'
```

Any idea on why it returns null? Is it not a valid Base64 encode?

Comment: ever figure out your problem?

Answer (score 5):

It means the `Auth.IdentityTokenXChangeData.Deserialize` method creates a new `MemoryStream` instance with a null `buffer` argument.

This method seems specific to your code / environment (there is an Auth.IdentityModule in your site), so you need to take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe the problem is with Encoded value in the QueryString ("F960866879F669E=Tw5NpFeW9HsAqc_Ap5dmOwqkZ041pFQGYLxRV-puumtHsfhrTYtDe51uCbGV44Kc1X3n6cggsynfqRmh74ie535ymkvATeK5Jii11tOMIZDZ_GVB8QolLeMU5i6KWEZculKhM0IOhYFaMc-DsB") - The Base64 Decode is returning 'null' for some reasons. (Method System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(base64Package))